# How do I add styles to an external widget

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js

I am new to NextJS and trying to implement a custom stylesheet into my code with a third party widget and having no luck. The names I am using for the style sheet I know match what the third party is expecting as I received this information from them. I am importing the sheet on the page where it will be used and not adding this to the globals file.

I am using a third party widget loaded through a script. Their code gets the elementById.

`var widgetDiv = document.getElementById('widget');`

I have a style sheet that I am not sure how to implement. Here is the import of the style sheet

`import styles from '../styles/widget.module.css';`

Here is an example of the stylesheet

```
.widget-table tr th {padding: 8px 0px; background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245); border: 1px solid rgb(190, 190, 190); color: rgb(80, 80, 80); line-height: 1.3; text-align: center;}

.widget-table-mobile-row {display: none}

.widget-day-cell {font-weight: 600; text-align: center; min-width: 100px; max-width: 125px; padding: 0px 5px; margin: 0px;}
```

The following code I added to implement the styles, but nothing happens.

```
<div id="widget" className={styles["widget-next-available-line"]}></div>
```

Please let me know how to properly implement the styles.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override the element with the ID of "widget", you could use the id selector in your CSS file like so:-

```
#widget {
    //add your style here
}
```

If this doesn't work, add !important to each style so it takes priority.